# iframe z-index dropdown menu

Tags: iframe, drop-down-menu, z-index

Due to the structure of my website, I am forced to use a iframe to display the dropdown menu html file. if not, I am not able to see the dropdown in IE. Here is the code I am using:

```html
<iframe id="a"name="FRAMENAME" src="http://website.com/dropdown.html" 
width="1000" style="position:relative" background="#F3F0ED" style="z-index:10000" 
height="40" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowautotransparency=true></iframe>
```

Now the problem is that the dropdown is hiding behind the other images on the website. I have specified `position:relative and z-index:10000` but I cannot get it to overlap on the images. The z-index of these images is much less than 10000. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2):

if your images are outside of your iFrame, of course your dropdown menu will not show up since you are trying to tell the dropdown menu to go out of its windows.  iframe is a different window inside your html, therefore any overflow of the window will never go out, elements inside the iframe is not affected with the `z-index`.

what you could do is, if your `http://website.com/dropdown.html` has the dropdown content only, you can call it by jQuery

```
<div id="myDropDown">
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myDropDown").load("http://website.com/dropdown.html");
    });    
</script>
```

this will append the content of your `dropdown.html` into the `div`

Comment: so you are telling me there is no solution for this? I have completed re-designed the website, but I still want to know if there was any solution for this problem?

Comment: @Scorpion King, if you're iframe content is only for dropdown why put it in an iFrame?

Comment: the structure of my website is asking me include the dropdown.html, and when i use normal include, the dropdown is not working for IE. looks fine in everything else though. When i use iframe, the dropdown is working in IE as well. so i wanted to go ahead with iframe.

Comment: how did you do it when you include it normally? maybe if you could post some codes I can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Just add "wmode=transparent" after "?"

don't remember!!  set Property dropdown z-index too.